# When passing data in a stack navigator with lots of screens, will parameters be carried forward from previous screens?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I have a stack navigator in React Native with around 14 screens. When a user clicks next, I use navigation.navigate to go to the next page. I have a lot of parameters and I want to know if I have to explicitly write out each parameter each time the user goes to the next page, or will it carry over from before?

E.g to navigate between screen 1 and screen 2, it passes the value of email:

```
navigation.navigate("Screen2", {
    email: await getData("email"),
});
```

Then on Screen 2, it navigates to screen 3, not writing email as a parameter:

```
navigation.navigate("Screen3", 
    username: uname.trim(),
});
```

Will screen 3 be able to access/use route.params.email, since it was passed from Screen 1 to Screen 2?

I'm struggling to understand the existing code and thought this might be a solution to the problem I'm facing. The value 'email' is not used in every screen but it is used in both screen 1 and screen 9, so in between this value is not passed between the screens.

Comment: No. Email will undefined in Sreen3. If you want use `email`(Screen1 pass to Screen2) in Screen3, you need pass it from Screen2 to Screen3. But if you want use in Screen14, it so complex because need pass email over 13 screens. So using State management library like Redux, Recoil will be easy for this case.

Answer (score 0):

No, email will not be available in the nested screens where you didn't pass the email as a param.

I suggest you to use [React Context Api](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context), its great for smaller projects for state management.

If your project is large with more than 30 40 screens then you can go with such libraries like Redux and Recoil.

I hope this answer will help you out. Thanks!